# phpmyadmin hangs and only imports about 50% of the database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using linux with phpadmin and trying to import a database. However it hangs about halfway through and just keeps constantly loading. I actually have to reset my computer and when I go check the tables, I get to about letter "F" on the tables list, each and every time. No errors, just a constant loading and a incomplete imported database.

I have already went into php config files and updated the post sizes and upload sizes, ect. But I am still getting this issue. Any help?

Comment: copy the file onto the server and import it from the console: `mysql -uroot -p databasename < /path/to/dump.sql` (if root is your user) (drop/create database first). At least this is the most reliable way. (Given you have access to the console ofc.)

Comment: I tried it, but it only gave me the following error in the terminal:

ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '��]W'.

Comment: where does the dump come from? (i.e. how was it created)

Comment: I got the database file from pantheon site, using it to work on a friends website but want to use a local copy. The file size itself is only 6.2MB so size shouldn't be a problem, yet it just hangs halfway through.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is compressed, like gzip or something?

Comment: Yes, it is. It says "databasename.sql.gz"

Comment: then extract it before attempting the import: `gunzip databasename.sql.gz` followed by `mysql -uroot -p databasename < /path/to/databasename.sql` (NO .gz)

Comment: atleast this time I got a error message and it didn't hang! but this is from phpmyadmin, I will try the console now:

Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume.

After doing that, it gave me this:

Error

SQL query:

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */

MySQL said: Documentation
#1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Comment: Are you trying this on local environment (localhost) or on hosting?

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is limited by the PHP resource limits; memory, execution timeout, and so on. Depending on your situation, your file upload may take so long that the timeout is reached, or uncompressing the file may result in exceeding the memory limits.

You can try a few things:

- Uncompress the file locally, then upload the .sql file
- Use the "[UploadDir](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir)" feature to place the file in a folder on your web server, which phpMyAdmin can then access locally.
- Upload the .sql file and use the command line client, as suggested by @dognose. I tend to use the 'source' syntax; after connecting to the `mysql` command line client just use `source database.sql`. Depending on the .sql file, you may first have to create and/or `use` the database.